# how can I structure an association relationship for di?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have a UserRepository and GroupRepository. The UserRepository has a GetUsers(includeGroups) method. The GroupsRepository has a GetGroups(includeUsers) method. Therefore the UserRepository uses the GroupsRepository and the GroupsRepository uses the UserRepository. My application uses MEF for DI but for now I'm just instantiating dependency member variables from the constructors.

The scenario described in the first paragraph above is returning a StackOverflowException b/c each repo keeps instantiating the other.  What are some common design patterns for managing this type relationship scenario?

Sample code here:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z03rHw

Comment: Maybe some code could turn your scenario cleaner to the community

Comment: @RicardoPontual - I added a dotnetfiddle with sample code to my original post